# Can my multi-conditional JS form validation be more effecient?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Given a form that requires either vehicle license plate (number & state), AND/OR a valid VIN number, I would like to know how my attempt at validation could be improved. This was my approach.

#1  See if all three fields are empty. If all three are empty the form can not be submitted.

#2 If VIN is not empty, is it valid? If not, do not submit form.

#3 If either plate number or state are not empty / selected, then check to see if the other is. If not, form is not submitted.

I am using the returnVal for final submission condition.

Please note I am very much an amateur, but I wanted to at least show my effort. I am hoping to learn by using a more efficient method if possible.

```
var lPlate = $('#license_plate').val();
var lState = $( '#plate_state' ).val();
var vin = $('#VIN').val();


if(lPlate === '' && lState === '' && vin === ''){
$("#vehicleID").show();
returnVal = false;
}


if(vin != ''){
if(!valvin(vin)){
$("#vehicleID").show();
document.getElementById("VIN").style.borderColor = "red";
document.getElementById("VIN").style.setProperty("--c", "red");
document.getElementById("VIN").style.color = "red";
sibling = document.getElementById("VIN").previousElementSibling;
sibling.style.display = "inline-block";
returnVal = false;
}
}

if(valvin(vin)){
document.getElementById("VIN").style.borderColor = "black";
document.getElementById("VIN").style.setProperty("--c", "black");
document.getElementById("VIN").style.color = "black";
}

if(lPlate === '' && lState != ''){
document.getElementById("license_plate").style.color = "red";
$("#vehicleID").show();
returnVal = false;
}
if(lPlate != '' && lState === ''){
$("#vehicleID").show();
returnVal = false;
}
```

Comment: If you're beginner then why is there jQuery? Why the mix of "vanilla" JavaScript and jQuery? (And why is there no jQuery tag?)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve] (with proper indentation)

Comment: The reason there is a mix is likely that I'm a beginner.